# Loading windmill layer from Vindbrukskollen's map to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, layers, arcgis-rest-api, web-service

My aim is to visualize the windmill locations at QGIS from [Vindbrukskollen's map](https://vbk.lansstyrelsen.se/). To achieve this, right click on the map, select Inspect. I find this link (highlighted in blue, cursor over it):

[image]

Copying it here:

https://ext-geodata-applikationer.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/rest/services/VBK/lst_vbk_read/MapServer/export?dynamicLayers=%5B%5D&dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png32&bbox=266751.24243930646%2C6410467.740252377%2C551121.8258585681%2C6538509.733104119&bboxSR=3006&imageSR=3006&size=1890%2C851&layers=show%3A-1%2C-1%2C-1&f=image

From the ...`arcgis/rest`... part, I think I should add this layer to QGIS as an ArcGIS REST Server.

In QGIS, I do `Layer -> Add Layer -> Add ArcGIS REST Server Layer -> New` and paste the above link into the URL field, with a name `Sweden1`:

[image]

Click `OK`, then `Connect`, and I get:

```
Connection failed: Parsing error
```

[image]

The little windmill symbol did make it into QGIS, just left to `Sweden1` text, indicating that I am probably on the right track.

**How to solve this parsing error to add Vindbrukskollen's windmill layer to QGIS?**

Comment: There's a WMS service you can use: https://ext-geodata-applikationer.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/services/VBK/lst_vbk_wms_vindbrukskollen/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS from: https://ext-geodatakatalog.lansstyrelsen.se/GeodataKatalogen/GetMetaDataById?id=ed5814b2-08bf-493a-a164-7819e1b590d6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the individual layers if you shorten the URL to:

```
https://ext-geodata-applikationer.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/rest/services/VBK/lst_vbk_read/MapServer/
```

[image]